# How to set Jetty's overall logging level SLF4J+Logback?

Tags: java, jetty, slf4j, logback

I am using Jetty http client in my application. I am also using SLF4J with LogBack.

How to set Jetty's overall logging level to INFO?

I have followed the instructions on Jetty's documentation to provide jetty-logging.properties file with contents like this:

```
# Configure Jetty for SLf4j Logging
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
# Overall Logging Level is INFO
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO
```

Jetty is logging fine via SLF4J, but the LEVEL setting doesn't seem to work.

When I set the level from Logback configuration then it works, but I want my code to be logged in DEBUG level and Jetty in INFO level.

Jetty is very noisy in DEBUG level.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make Jetty to log at custom level. Because if Jetty finds SLF4J in my application then it will start using it with the logging level I have specified in logback.xml configuration file.

So I made a little hack. I specified Jetty to use Java Utils Logging and set level to INFO.

```
            // Setting Jetty logger implementation and level (DEBUG | INFO | WARN | IGNORE)
            System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class",
                    "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog");
            System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class.LEVEL", "INFO");
```

And for redirecting Java Utils Logging messages to SLF4J I used jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar

That's how I got it working. If there is a better way I sure want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Properties....

```
    // change Jetty Logger

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "OFF");
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog.setProperties(p);
```